# Does Anylogic provide the option of saving datasets to Excel/csv-files after the running an experiment?

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I am building my first anylogic model. I collect the values of important variables in datasets while the simulation is running. How can I save this data automatically to an excel/csv file once the run finishes?

According to the Big Book of Simulation Modeling, there is the option of saving data to a database but I am using a computer without MS Access and admin rules don't allow me to install new software.

Answer (score 0):

there's a whole chapter on the help documentation about how to use excel api to write data into your excel
https://anylogic.help/api/com/anylogic/engine/connectivity/ExcelFile.html

You need to use an excel object from the connectivity palette

Then you can do things such as

```
excel.setCellValue(value, sheetIndex, rowIndex, columnIndex);
excel.writeFile();
```

to write a dataset you do

```
excel.writeDataSet​(DataSet dataSet, int sheetIndex, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
```